# Get the unique values of two vectors keeping the order of both original

Tags: r

I am trying to get a vector of the unique elements of two vectors that respects the order of both of the original vectors.

The vectors are both sampled from a longer "hidden" vector that only contains unique entries (i.e. no repeats are allowed), which ensures both v1 and v2 have a compatible order (i.e. v1<-("Z","A",...) and v2<-("A","Z",...) can not occur).

The order is arbitrary, so I cannot use any simple order() or sort().
An example below:

```
v1 <- c("Z", "A", "F", "D")
v2 <- c("A", "T", "F", "Q", "D")
```

Result desired:

```
c("Z", "A", "T", "F", "Q", "D") or
```

Further explanation: v1 establishes the relationship
"Z" < "A" < "F" < "D"
and v2 states
"A" < "T" < "F" < "Q" < "D"
so the sequence that satisfies v1 and v2 is
"Z" < "A" < "T" < "F" < "Q" < "D"

I understand this case is fully determined (the two vectors do completely define the order of all elements), but there would be cases when this is not enough. In that case, any permutation that respects the two sets of ordering would be a satisfactory solution.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that not. Each vector defines an order and both are compatible. In `v2` one has `Q < D` so in the final vector one should have `Q < D`.

Comment: @iago. Thanks, that is exactly the case. The relative order in all vectors should be kept.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is poorly specified.  For example, why do you place "Q" ahead of "D" in your desired solution?  Is v2 getting priority over v1? As a simple example, if you have v1<-c("A","B") and v2<-c("B","A"), what is your desired result?  A,B or B,A? If you add a "Q" to the end of v1, this situation occurs...

Comment: @AdrianTompkins As I told above there is not priority of any vector. The question asks for keeping the order of **both** original vectors, so your `v1` and `v2` are not possible original vectors, since their orders are not compatible.

Comment: your solution gives "Z" "A" "T" "F" "D" "Q", if you add "Q" to the end of v1, so it is taking the order from v1 first. But  My point is simply that the question should be clarified to specify what to do if this situation arises (catch it and throw an error, or take the order from v1 as in your solution, or to state that it is not allowed) and also how to handle repeats in a list for that matter. ps: nice solution by the way, I upvoted it, this is not a criticism of the answer, just a suggestion that the question needs clarification

Comment: @AdrianTompkins I know you were not commenting my answer. On it, I just have to say that I assumed that the order in both vectors is compatible, so the cases you raise cannot occur, and I do not check that. To my understanding, the question does not include this possibility; otherwise, I agree with you it should clarify what to do in those cases, I would bet for throw an error, but it is not my question...

Comment: So in fact, the problem is essentially that v1 and v2 are sub-samples from a third "hidden" longer vector that only contains unique entries. This would ensure that both vectors have a compatible order and repeats are not allowed. :-)

Comment: @AdrianTompkins Yes you are right. In the case you suggest the two vectors would be contradicting each other (it is not possible that "Q" < "D" AND "Q" > "D").  Your latest concept (samples of a "hidden" longer vector) frames it better than I did. If you have a suggestion on how to check this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question to (hopefully) become clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example the next code works. One first has to define auxiliar vectors `w1`, `w2` depending on which has the first common element and another vector `w` on which to append the lacking elements by order.

It would be clearer using a `for` loop, which would avoid this cumbersome code, but at first, this is faster and shorter.

```r
w <- w1 <- unlist(ifelse(intersect(v1,v2)[1] == v1[1], list(v2), list(v1)))
w2 <- unlist(ifelse(intersect(v1,v2)[1] == v1[1], list(v1), list(v2)))
unique(lapply(setdiff(w2,w1), function(elmt) w <<- append(w, elmt, after = match(w2[match(elmt,w2)-1],w)))[[length(setdiff(w2,w1))]])
[1] "Z" "A" "T" "F" "Q" "D"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get `unique` from `v1` and `v2` and resort it using `match` on `v1` and `v2` and repeat this until no change happens.

```
x <- unique(c(v1, v2))
repeat {
  y <- x
  i <- match(v2, x)
  x[sort(i)] <- x[i]
  i <- match(v1, x)
  x[sort(i)] <- x[i]
  if(identical(x, y)) break;
}
x
#[1] "Z" "A" "T" "F" "Q" "D"
```

Alternative you can get the overlapping letters of `v1` and `v2` and then join to this anchor points the subsets of `v1` and `v2`:

```
i <- v2[na.omit(match(v1, v2))]
j <- c(0, match(i, v2))
i <- c(0, match(i, v1))
unique(c(unlist(lapply(seq_along(i)[-1], function(k) {
  c(v1[head((i[k-1]:i[k]), -1)], v2[head((j[k-1]:j[k])[-1], -1)])
})), v1, v2))
#[1] "Z" "A" "T" "F" "Q" "D"
```